# Trim string to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, string, rgb, trim

I have a string like this: `rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236, 0.84839234)`

How can I trim the string of the last number to two decimal places (`0.84`) and remove everything after the decimal for the other ones?

For example:

```
rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236, 0.84839234)
```

Should be:

```
rgba(244, 3, 3, 0.84)
```

Comment: Do you not want/need the number to be "rounded"? e.g. `0.84839234` _~>_ `0.85`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to find the numbers you want, and then reconstruct the string:

```
function convert(inputStr) {
  const groups = inputStr.match(/\((?<r>[\d]*).*, ?(?<g>[\d]*).*, ?(?<b>[\d]*).*, ?(?<a>[\d]*\.?\d{0,2}).*\)/).groups;
  return `rgba(${groups.r}, ${groups.g}, ${groups.b}, ${groups.a})`;
}
// Function call
convert("rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236, 0.84839234)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var string = "rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236, 0.84839234)";
var numbers = string.match(/([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/g).map(Number);
```

Then in `numbers` array you will have those numbers and you can do whatever you want with them. First do manipulations, then just concat them in the string that you desire.

For example:

```
var newString = `rgba(${Math.floor(numbers[0])}, ${Math.floor(numbers[1])}, ${Math.floor(numbers[2])}, ${numbers[3].toFixed(2)})`
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious: why `Math.floor` over `Math.round`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try without regex then ...

```
const string = "rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236, 0.84839234)";
const rgbaValues = string.substring(string.indexOf('(') + 1, string.length - 1).split(",");
const returnString = `rgba(${parseInt(rgbaValues[0])}, ${parseInt(rgbaValues[1])}, ${parseInt(rgbaValues[2])}, ${parseFloat(rgbaValues[3]).toFixed(2)})`;
console.log(returnString);
```

Answer (score 0):

To trim a number of a few decimals use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). e.g.

```js
Math.PI;
//=> 3.141592653589793
Math.PI.toFixed(2)
//=> "3.14"
```

To replace parts of a string use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). e.g.

```js
const reverse_cc = str =>
  str.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g,
    (ignore, x1, x2, x3, x4) =>
      `${x4}-${x3}-${x2}-${x1}`);

reverse_cc("Hey this is my credit card number: 1234-2345-3456-4567");
//=> "Hey this is my credit card number: 4567-3456-2345-1234"
```

With this knowledge we can build a function that extracts the numbers within a `rgba(...)` string, processes these numbers and returns a new string:

```js
const rgba_fix = str =>
  str.replace(/rgba\(\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\)/,
    (ignore, x1, x2, x3, x4) =>
      Array.of(
        [ Math.round(Number(x1))
        , Math.round(Number(x2))
        , Math.round(Number(x3))
        , Number(x4).toFixed(2)
        ])
      .map(xs => `rgba(${xs.join(', ')})`)
      [0]);

rgba_fix('rgba(244.235, 3.234, 3.236 , 0.84839234)');
//=> "rgba(244, 3, 3, 0.85)"
```